# Serve Index Page for Public Directory in CKAN

Tags: plugins, webserver, ckan, static-files

In a custom CKAN extension (https://github.com/berlinonline/ckanext-berlin_dataset_schema), I serve some static files with documentation. The folder with the static files is included in the extension at `ckanext/berlin_dataset_schema/public/schema`, and is registered via `ckan.plugins.toolkit.add_public_directory()` (see https://github.com/berlinonline/ckanext-berlin_dataset_schema/blob/master/ckanext/berlin_dataset_schema/plugin.py#L34).

This works: there is an `index.html` page in the `schema` folder which is served at `/schema/index.html` in the CKAN site. However, I would like CKAN to also serve `index.html` for requests to `schema`.

Of course this can be achieved by configuring the web server in which CKAN is running, but I would prefer a way to achieve this within CKAN. Is this possible?